# How to pass table name dynamically to sql query in cursor.execute in Python?

Tags: python, sql, cursor

```
   cur.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME LIKE [{}]".format(tableName))
```

This is my code, but table names are not displaying.
Maybe the problem here is in format.

Comment: are you looking for table names or columns names ? tables are available with `"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME  LIKE %s"`

Comment: I want column name from the table which is stored already in a variable.Thats y : `SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE %s`

Comment: so the answer below is the solution, but if you get errors with another part of code, you should add it, or post another question

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters!  In Python, this looks like

```
cur.execute("""
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ?""", (tableName))
```

Some databases may prefer `%s` rather than `?`.

Comment: Once i am using this syntax, the rest of the code isnt working.It works if `code`cur.execute("""
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)`code`